# Excel Determine if All Components in A List are Present in Another List Per Variable

Tags: excel, comparison

I have used Index Match array formulas and the like before but am not sure if it will suffice in this instance.

Table 1: a list of Adobe products installed on devices.

- Col A has Product Name and Col B has Device Name

Table 2: a list of the products that come in Adobe Design Standard Suite:

- Illustrator
- Indesign
- Photoshop

I need a way to flag every device in table 1 which has all the component products of Adobe Design Standard Suite. (I have already normalized the data.)

I will ultimately need to compare against 3 different Adobe suites, but I can do each comparison separately.

Dynamic VBA solutions are acceptable, but I prefer a formula in this instance.

---

**EDIT** Attempt to add sample data. I want to know which devices in table one have all the products in table 2.

*TABLE 1*
**Product...........................Device Name  |  Desired Result**
Adobe Dreamweaver CC | Device1     |    FALSE
Adobe Illustrator CC........  | Device1    |    FALSE
Adobe InDesign CC.........  | Device1      |   FALSE
Adobe Dreamweaver CC | Device2     |    FALSE
Adobe Illustrator CC.........| Device3     |    TRUE
Adobe InDesign CC..........| Device3       |    TRUE
Adobe Photoshop CC.......| Device3     |    TRUE

*TABLE 2*
**Design Standard Suite Compenents**
Adobe Illustrator CC
Adobe InDesign CC
Adobe Photoshop CC

Comment: Could you at least attempt to construct two very small tables of sample data, together with expected results?

Comment: I did my best - edited the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a helper column:

```
=IF(MATCH(A3,Table2,0)>0,1,0)
```

in conjunction with:

```
=IFERROR(SUMIF(B:B,B3,C:C)=3,"FALSE")
```

Comment: I had to adjust a little but it ended up working. Where DesignStd is the named range of the suite components.

=COUNTIF(DesignStd, $A2)  |   
=AND(IF(SUMIF($B:$B,$B2,$F:$F)=COUNTA(DesignStd),TRUE, FALSE), IF(SUMIF($B:$B,$B2,$F:$F)=COUNTIF(B:B, B2), TRUE, FALSE))

COUNTIF won't produce errors if the lookup value is not found in DesignStd range.  

My multi-IF statement is a little more dynamic so I can just change the named range to check against all suite possibilities, and it results in TRUE if and only if the sum of products per device equals the number of products in the suite exactly.